# Android destroy activity with finish() in onPause()

Tags: android, locationmanager

I dont think putting  finish() in onPause() is cutting it.

I have a Location activity and it is proving very hard to test, what I would like to do is be able to, when I leave the activity, completely destroy/kill any existence of it. So that when I go back, both when I leave the app or just the activity, everything is new, there is no cache, nothing and it has to start all over again.

The reason being is I don’t want it to remember Last Know Locations, they are not useful in this app, all I want is the current location and if it can’t be found, it can’t be found.

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets into some deep discussions about how android manages activities and memory and all kinds of things which you probably don't want to think about.
If you are currently trying to finish the activity in your onPause method (sounds like a horrible idea to me since your phone will call this whenver your screen goes to sleep -- after about 15 seconds of inactivity depending on your settings). But if that really is what you want to do then why not just make the call to get the last known location in your onResume method?

Comment: My problem is I dont want to store anything, I want to look for the current location when the activity starts and then once the activity has been left, if the user comes back it has to find the current location all over again.

Comment: I've done some even more research into this and I'm very glad you brought up the "deep discussions" about memory, sometimes I think I'm going nuts with Android!!!, things dont change when I make changes and so on. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Put finish in onPause and in manifest add this for that activity `android:stateNotNeeded="true"` 
so it want remember your last state on relaunch of that activity

Answer (score 0):

For solving this problem you can use **preferences** for storing the data and you can use it for future.